# create sense query by sql query

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, sense

I want to get years and apply group by on it to get the counts of record. For this my SQL query is  -

```
select substr(lastModified,0,4) , count(*) from EOM group by substr(lastModified,0,4).
```

I created query for above is -

```
      {
"size":0,
    "aggs": {
        "profit": {
            "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script" : "_agg.transactions = []",
                "map_script" : "_agg.transactions.add(doc.timeModified.date.getYear())", 
                "combine_script" :  "return _agg.transactions"

            }
        },
        "aggs":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"profit"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RESULT -**

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "profit": {
            "value": [
                [
                    2014,
                    2015,
                    2016,
                    2015,
                    2017

                ],
                [
                    2015,
                    2015,
                    2016,
                    2016,
                    2017
                ]
            ]
        },
        "aggs": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
        }
    }
}
```

It give me years but not apply aggrgation on profit and its bucket is blank.

I want sense query for the above sql query.

Comment: What is the output/error with the query you posted above?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen post update!!

Comment: post update!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Date Range aggregation instead of a scripted metric ?

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html

(the only drawback is that you will have to manually provide the years in ranges section)

Comment: Data Range needs the ranges and I don't have the start and end year values in my indexes

Comment: if you want ranges by year, you can specify from 1st january to 31 december of each year

Comment: update post, The result is as display above and I want the no. of count of the year which are repeat in result(means group by query)